# How to Integrate one time password (OTP) option with registration form in SAP Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

My requirement is to integrate **one time password (OTP)** for registration form with **mobile number** as additional field. So that at the time of registration user will receive **one time password (OTP)** on **mobile number**. By submitting correct  OTP the User will get validated and confirmed for registration. How to achieve the same?
Regards,
Niraj Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You need make change on registration form and register controller. First post, validate form and trigger sms service for OTP. Save OTP and phone number to session and show OTP field on register form. In second post validate form OTP with session OTP.